# editable graph tool in python to website

Tags: python, graph

I have tons of json files and I'd like to see their connections with each other on my website as a network graph. There are a lot of tools for that in python, but my extra wish is to manipulate these network graphs: the vertex should be clickable, removable and the user can draw a line between two vertex so a new connection gets created.

Similar stuff can be done with vis.js, node.js, neo4j, arangodb, but as I see python libraries for that like seaborn, plotly, bokeh, their graphs are not interactive.

Should I go ahead and get to know with js tools mentioned above or are there something like this already written in python?

Thanks

Comment: See [this](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/json_graph.html) and [this](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/drawing.html)

Comment: Networkx gives you all the functionality you need to do the things mentioned in your question

Comment: thanks for your answer! As I read networkx documentation I saw that I need to use  some javascript to achieve the things I wrote (especially the online graph editing). Can I make without js or if I can't, which one do you recommend? d3.js, vis.js, sigma js? Thx

Comment: I have more experience with sigma js, but all should be fine

Comment: Can you help me where to put the folder that I downloaded form the sigmajs site in flask (to static)? It contains a lot of files - xmls, jss, several inner folders. The best would be to reach sigmajs remotely in flask through a link or something. Is it possible? thanks

Comment: You are probably better off using Google/another question to help you with that